# Component this.props logging undefined in console, but shows up in React Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-props

Private Route definition:

```
PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
                <Route {...rest} render={props => (
                    this.state.isAuthenticated
                    ? <Component {...props} />
                    : <Redirect to="/" />
                )}/> 
            )
```

Passing in props in router to `Home`:

```
<this.PrivateRoute path="/home" exact component={Home} portalId={this.state.portalId} />
```

React developer tools shows:
[image]

Console logs:
[image]

Where is my `props.portalId`? I am setting the `this.props.portalId` after a fetch in another component so this may be the problem because of the asynchronous call? How would I fix this in that case?

Edit: Console.log is being called in `Home's componentDidMount()`:

```
class Home extends Component {     
  componentDidMount() {
     console.log(this.props.portalId);
}
```

Comment: Where is the console.log? There are other props that are also missing

Comment: @BernardoFerreiraBastosBraga I edited original post to show where console is logged

Comment: How do you set this.props.portalId? Props should not be overwritten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see props, you should pass props to the component rendered by `<Route />`, instead you pass props to the `<Route />`.

You can use render attribute instead of component like this:

```
<Route to="/anywhere" render={() => <YourComponent {...yourProps} />} />
```

I use once `component` prop:

```
<Route to="/anywhere" component={() => <YourComponent {...yourProps} />} />
```

It is worked, but recomended to use `render`.

It discussed sometimes on [github](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5521) , you can see.

## Edit to working example:

```
PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
            <Route render={props => (
                this.state.isAuthenticated
                ? <Component {...props} {...rest}  />
                : <Redirect to="/" />
            )}/> 
        )
```

I emulate your example in my env, i placed rest object in `<Component />` definition, its worked for me, try it and see what happens.

**It works when I do this:**

```
PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
                <Route {...rest} render={() => (
                    this.state.isAuthenticated
                    ? <Component {...this.props}/>
                    : <Redirect to="/" />
                )}/> 
            )

<this.PrivateRoute path="/home" exact component={() => <Home portalId={this.state.portalId} />} />
```

Comment: Hi, you've helped me on another question of mine before, thanks.
I am using component in the Router because in my `PrivateRoute` definition I am already calling render.

Comment: I see, but your still pas props on <Route /> as prop. So, to solve this problem you need to pass it anywhere instead <Route />

Comment: I'm not fully understanding where I should pass the props. Should I do it in the `PrivateRoute` definition or in the `BrowserRouter`

Comment: I edit my answer, try to remove rest from `<Route />` and pass to the <Component />

Comment: I edited your answer. I move the props into `component={() => ....` and it works, but I do think the component is being render twice now

Comment: Yes, thanks, i think it render twice because {...rest} props update `<Route />` too, but i am not sure, try to remove them and see what happens

Comment: I remove `{...rest}` but still being rendered multiple times unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe it heppens from rendering parent component, console.log how much renders parent component?

Comment: `Home` only has `routes.js` as parent component

Comment: Yea, but you check state of parent component ? `this.state.isAuthenticated`

Comment: `this.state.isAuthenticated` is in the same component as the routes.

Comment: Yea, so maybe it rerender multiple time?

Comment: I can't find it. It's ok no big deal